# Mailgun: Domain is not allowed to send large batches yet

Tags: mailgun, postfix-mta, mailman

I am running a mailing list with Mailman which uses Postfix to send the emails through Mailgun. I'm on Mailgun's (paid) Flex plan with a verified (non-sandbox) account.

The mailing list has about 30 members and the traffic is low. Still, when an email is sent, the log (`/var/log/mail.log`) contains entries with `Domain ... is not allowed to send large batches yet`.

```
postfix/smtp[33682]: 019053E815: to=<...>, relay=smtp.mailgun.org[44.231.238.210]:587,
  delay=1181, delays=1179/0.02/2/0.13, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host smtp.mailgun.org[44.231.238.210]
  said: 421 Domain ... is not allowed to send large batches yet (in reply to DATA command))
```

I was unable to find any information about this error message. What's a good workaround for this issue – should the outgoing emails be throttled or should I request an increase of the batch sizes from Mailgun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to contact Mailgun support. They raised the limits on my account and after that, the emails got delivered – the `mail.log` file now has `status=sent (250 Great success)` entries.